# How to sharea file from Android app to other device via bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, share, send

**Hi,
I'm developing an app on android studio that allows me to send a txt file, which I create from the EditText, to another device via Bluetooth, my code is this:**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri text=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/doc/mytext.txt");
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,BLUETOOTH_SERVICE));
```

---

**I can share the file via whatsapp without problems but via bluetooth I have the following errors:**
[
on:
Bluetooth file sent:
Successful operations: 0, Non-tripping operations: 4.

under:
Bluetooth: file Unknown file not sent][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O62fx.jpg)

[unknown file
Laptop ..
The request could not be correctly managed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKzau.jpg)

**I have set the following permissions on the Android Manifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: What kind of device, os, app is on the other side of the bluetooth connection? And you are only sending a path of your file. Not the file itself. So how would the receiver read the content of a file that is not on its device? How did you implement a file transfer?

Comment: I answer the questions, I hope to be clear:
1 on the other side of the Bluetooth connection I have a laptop (windows 10).
2 I created the file previously with a method that creates a folder (doc) in the phone memory and inside it writes the typed content of the EditText into a txt file (named text.txt). It works perfectly, in fact I can find the file text.txt with the file management app and if I open it I find what I wrote in the EditText.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: sorry but it is not clear to me why with this code the txt file (no string or path) I can send it on whatsapp without problems.
While with Bluetooth no.

Comment: Yes. Clear. Whatsapp is running on the same device and has acces to that path and can read the file. The laptop has no acces to files on your device.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: That i already told you twice: what about file transfer?

Comment: I found this guide can be useful?https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Comment: That can help you during programming of transfer code yes. Do you have an application running on your laptop where you can communicate with? With which your app on Android can transfer a file?

Comment: yes my computer has built-in bluetooth and so I just go to settings and move to "Bluetooth and Other devices" -> "Send or receive files via Bluetooth".
I didn't understand what you mean in the second question

Comment: `"Send or receive files via Bluetooth"` . It looks as if the laptop has some inbuild software for file transfer. Well find out how it works. The protocol and so. I have no idea.